# How can I pass an object on click of anchor Tag

Tags: javascript, html

I have a function which is creating an anchor tag and on click of anchor tag I am passing some parameter. How can I pass an object on click of anchor Tag.

Here is my code

```
var obj = {
  "Name": "USA",
  "id": 1,
  "CON": "NA",
  "VAl": "TS"
}

if (obj.VAl) {
  obj.text = "<a style='color:#0000ff' onClick='openMyData(event," + obj + ")' href='javascript:void(0);'>" + "</a>";
}
```

But on click I am getting **Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier** debugger is not firing at `openMyData`. If I gave my value like `obj.VAl` then it is firing. Can anyone please help what I am missing.

onclick even code :

```
function openMyData(evt, obj){
    var win = window.open('someURL',"","resizable=yes,menubar=no,status=yes,scrollbars=no", fullscreen = "1");
    win.resizeTo(screen.availWidth, screen.availHeight);
    win.moveTo(0, 0);
    win.focus();
}
```

I wanted my object to be in the scope of new window.

Comment: check my updated answer. Should work for you.

Comment: Thanks. I am testing this

Comment: Where is this new Window? Same domain?

Comment: @zer00ne yes in same domain. when I am trying to give value like `win.objVal = obj` this is not working, but when I am giving `win.name = "someNme"` i am getting `this.name`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do `JSON.stringify(obj)` like this

```
if (obj.VAl) {
  obj.text = "<a style='color:#0000ff' onClick='openMyData(event,'" + JSON.stringify(obj) + "')' href='javascript:void(0);'>" + "</a>";
}
```

With the `JSON.stringify(obj)` surrounded by the quotes. Then you can parse it in `openMyData` function to get the actual object.

```
function openMyData(evt, obj){
    var win = window.open('someURL?objValue='+ obj,"","resizable=yes,menubar=no,status=yes,scrollbars=no", fullscreen = "1");
    win.resizeTo(screen.availWidth, screen.availHeight);
    win.moveTo(0, 0);
    win.focus();
}
```

Then on the new window you can get that value with parameter `objValue` and then parse that value to get the entire object.

Comment: Can't I pass like `'someURL',"","resizable=yes,menubar=no,status=yes,scrollbars=no", fullscreen = "1", objValue='+ obj`

Comment: Seems like you just found why we need to use `addEventListener` over `onclick` attribute https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener :)

Answer (score -1):

you missed the comma between json variable.

```
var obj = {
  "Name": "USA",
  "id": 1,
  "CON": "NA",
  "VAl": "TS"
}

if (obj.VAl) {
  obj.text = "<a style='color:#0000ff' onClick='openMyData(event," + obj + ")' href='javascript:void(0);'>" + "</a>";
}
```

Comment: I've formatted your code - add 4 spaces at the beginning of the line to do this in the future. It is now appearing more correctly. Double check the code and improve your answer by including an explanation.